# How to write dynamic routing for SEO friendly URL's in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I have loaded the dynamic category data by using redux and data is as follows:

```
const categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Luxury Boats', url: 'luxury-boat-hire' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Super Yacht Hire', url: 'super-yacht-hire' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Whitsundays', url: 'luxury-boat-hire-whitsundays' },
    { id: 4, name: 'New Years Eve Cruises', url: 'new-years-eve-cruises' }
];
```

I created one component with name of Category.js . I have to write the Router code to override the URL. As per router

```
<Router path=”/category/:id” exact component={Category} />
```

When I use the NavLink and write the code to design NavBar then I used the following code.

```
{
  Categories.map(category => {
    return <NavLink to={`/category/${category.id}`}>{category.name}</NavLink>
  });
}
```

Above code create the 4 url for 4 categories like

```
Id:1 => http://localhost:3000/category/1
Id:2 => http://localhost:3000/category/2
Id:3 => http://localhost:3000/category/3
Id:4 => http://localhost:3000/category/4
```

But I want to make a URL like follows and also want to get id params in Category.js component

```
Id:1 => http://localhost:3000/category/1   => http://localhost:3000/luxury-boat-hire
Id:2 => http://localhost:3000/category/2  => http://localhost:3000/super-yacht-hire
Id:3 => http://localhost:3000/category/3  => http://localhost:3000/luxury-boat-hire-whitsundays
Id:4 => http://localhost:3000/category/4  => http://localhost:3000/ new-years-eve-cruises
```

if I will pass category.url instead of category.id then how may I get Id property in Category.js component to fetch category details and all products associated to this category? I want to get id params in Category component and URL also in SEO friendly.

passing props={category.id} is possible for that pages which has fix URL. URL is change for each page and category data is loading from json data from mysql database. I read your posting and you have fixed URL /aboutus only. but in my case all URL and category name and ID loading from database.

when I use the following code to pass id to Category component then URL is working first time but when we refresh the page then categoryid become empty:

```
                to={{
                    pathname: props.link,
                    categoryid: props.id
                }}
```

Please help to write a code for this

Comment: Just use `category.url` instead of `category.id`?

Comment: You can use `path="/:cat"` and use `categories.find(cat => this.props.params.match.cat == cat.url)`

Comment: As a side note; you don't mention if you are using server side rendering. If not, your SEO friendly URLs won't really matter. They'll still be SEO unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

Just map to the url rather than category.id

```
{
  Categories.map(category => {
    return <NavLink to={`${category.url}`}>{category.name}</NavLink>
  });
}
```

Comment: You can pass props with navlink: <NavLink to={${...}} props={category.id} ... /> see this link: https://medium.com/@bopaiahmd.mca/how-to-pass-props-using-link-and-navlink-in-react-router-v4-75dc1d9507b4

Comment: why would that work ? when react router is rendering the categories via a category ID and not category URL.